# Finding sides of a trapezium

Tags: geometry

In a trapezium $ABCD$, $AB$ is parallel to $CD$ & $\angle D$ = $2\angle B$. If $DC =p $ and $ AD = q$ , then $AB = ?$

My attempt to solution is shown in the picture attached [image: My Attempt]

Comment: From the isosceles $\triangle EAB$ you can infer that $ AB = p +q$.  The second angle relation that you wrote does not necessarily hold.

Comment: Can you tell me how you deduced this fact

Comment: Your mistake is that you supposed that the trapezoid is isosceles but this is not given by the problem's statement. Well, you can prove in a very similar way as you did that $\triangle EDC $ and $ \triangle EAB $ are both isosceles. Then $AB = AE=AD+DE = AD + DC = q + p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you deduce $DE=p$ Check that $${DE\over AE}={DC\over AB}\implies {p\over p+q}={p\over AB}$$

Comment: IS this according to Basic Proportionality Theorem ?

Comment: @Amritanshu  Similarity of Triangles(CDE & ABE)..

Comment: @Amritanshu BPT is a consequence of Similarity

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Hint:** draw an angle bisector and show that it splits the original trapezoid in a parallelogram and an isosceles triangle. It follows that $AB=\color{green}{p}+\color{red}{q}$.

Comment: @Greg: proof fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following your direction of proof construction:

[image]

Setting $\theta = \angle ABC \implies \angle ADC = 2\theta$

Continuing lines $AD$ and $BC$ to find $E$, we find $\angle ECD = \theta $ from parallel line crossing. Then since $\angle  EDC = \beta = 180^\circ-2\theta, \angle CED = \theta$ also and $\triangle EDC$ is isosceles so $|ED|=|DC|=p$

Then $\triangle EDC$ and $\triangle EAB$ are similar so $|AB| = |AE| = p+q$